# Is it possible to split contents of a column and use it to join to another column in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a similar scenario to what's below. Is there a way to join the items audit table to the users table?
I would like the user Id of the user that last audited the items.

**Users table:**

```
| UserId | FirstName | LastName | Email                 |
|--------|-----------|----------|-----------------------|
| 00001  |  Bob      | Hackman  | bob.hackman@test.org  |
| 00002  |  Peter    | Slot     | peter.slot@test.org   |
```

**ItemAudit Table:**

```
| ItemId | LastAuditedBy | 
|--------|---------------|
| abcd1  | Bob Hackman   |
| qw341  | Peter Slot    |
| w2re1  | Bob Hackman   |
| fsdf1  | Bob Hackman   |
| wetr1  | Peter Slot    |
```

Comment: The obligatory comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really have the `id` in the audit table, but you can use:

```
select ia.*, u.*
from itemAudit ia left join
     users u
     on concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) = ia.lastauditedby
```